# Quantum Dot Surface Area to Volume Relationship

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science, non-linear-optics, optical-materials

Do the properties off quantum dots depend more on their surface area rather than the volume they occupy?
Depending on the case, then would quantum dots of different shapes show different properties?